# Oracle write Japanese characters

Tags: java, sql, oracle, sql-insert, cjk

We're curently using Oracle 12, and we can't insert Japanese characters into a table with a column with the type NVARCHAR2(255 CHAR), the result is always "¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿¿". We tried to insert data using SQL Developer, Java Program, and even a stored procedure but we always get the same result.

```
select * from nls_database_parameters;

NLS_RDBMS_VERSION   12.2.0.1.0
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   $
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH.MI.SSXFF AM TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH.MI.SSXFF AM
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD-MON-RR
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  .,
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8DEC
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    AMERICA
NLS_CURRENCY    $
NLS_TERRITORY   AMERICA
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
```

EDIT 1 : I can't just change the database parameters, DBA don't want to.

Comment: trying changing the `NLS_CHARACTERSET` to `AL32UTF8` and store your Japanese characters in VARCHAR2 itself. This should help you  - `alter database character set AL32UTF8;`

Comment: @SudiptaMondal, `alter database character set AL32UTF8` is not supported by Oracle and you **should not** use it. Follow official guideline from Oracle [Character Set Migration](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NLSPG/ch11charsetmig.htm#NLSPG979)

Comment: Perhaps this one helps [Globalization Support](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJDBC/global.htm#JJDBC28643)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit didn't know that, thank you. I thought we can alter the character set using `alter database` in 12c.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal, The support of this command stopped even in Oracle 10g, see [Database SQL Reference 10.1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_1004.htm#sthref2672). I would be very surprised if Oracle would have "reintroduced" it in 12c

Comment: I can see you've tried several clients, but are you sure the issue is with the inserted data, and not how those clients are displaying it when it's queried? What does `dump(<column>, 1016)` show you? How are you supplying the value when you do the insert?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue, after looking at the Oracle driver, I found an option that was disabled by default : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html

After setting it to true while starting the app, It manages to store Japanese characters in the database : -Doracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true